# Issue with sortColumn and multiple Stateful Grids in EXTjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I've recently switched to stateful grids in ExtJs 3.x -- I'm using the OOTB CookieProvider for state management.

The issue I'm encountering is when moving from Grid to Grid (each at a unique URL within the same site) If I render the first grid and apply a sort.. When I click to access the 2nd grid that load finds the sortColumn from the first grid and causes errors..

Has anyone encountered this?

Answer (score 0):

Setting a unique - stateId: attribute per grid solves this -